# Send request to get data after first request validated

Tags: node.js

I try to write a Node.js app to download data (in JSON format) from a website. This site provides an open API that first I send a GET request to them with a verify key (that they approved) to create a client session, then I can use other services. But after I send a verify request and it return "valid", I send another request and it return "access denied".
Here my code:

```
http.request(verifyURL, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(chunk));
            http.get(getDataURL, function(res){
                res.on('data', function(data){
                    console.log(data.toString());
                });
            });
        });
}).end();
```

I understand that the second request has been sent with a new `http.request` so the key isn't valid anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If their sessions are based on cookies (most likely), you're better off using the [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module (instead of the plain `http` module) to handle your requests, because it supports cookie persistence across subsequent requests (see [the example code](https://github.com/mikeal/request#examples) about how to enable cookie support).